# Unable to resolve ambiguity of Messengers in multiple ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `DropDownView` which contains a DropDownList as follows

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Item}"  Height="30"/>
```

The `DropDownViewModel` has 2 properties as follows

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _myList;
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList {
    get { return _myList; }
    set {
        if (_myList == value)
            return;

        _myList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyList");
    }
}

private string _item;
public string Item {
    get { return _item; }
    set {
        if (_item == value)
            return;

        _item = value;
        Messenger.Default.Send(_item);  //line1
        RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
    }
}
```

Now, I have multiple ViewModels which creates multiple instances of this `DropdownViewModel` as follows. Each ViewModel belong to a separate View and are in no way interconnected. (For simplicity consider only 2 view models created.)

**ViewModel1**

```
public class ViewModel1
{
    private readonly DropDownViewModel _ddVM1;
    public ViewModel1(){
        _ddVM1 = new DropDownViewModel();
        Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, this.GetItem1);
    }

    private void string GetItem1(string obj){
        //perform some function
    }

}
```

**ViewModel2**

```
public class ViewModel2 
{
    private readonly DropDownViewModel _ddVM2;
    public ViewModel2(){
        _ddVM2 = new DropDownViewModel();
        Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, this.GetItem2);
    }

    void string GetItem2(string obj){
        //perform some function
    }
}
```

Now when I run the application and select a value from `DropDownList` of any one View, always the first registered function is called(in this case `GetItem1`). I have tested the code with only one `Messenger.Default.Register` in only one `ViewModel` and the app runs fine. I have also tested the code whether multiple instances of `DropDownView` and `DropDownViewModel` are being created or not. There seems to be no issues in that area too.

I do not understand why such a scenario is occuring in case of more than one ViewModel as every `ViewModel` has its own `DropDownView` and `DropDownViewModel` instance. So what is exactly happening internally? Why is the app behaving in a weird manner on `line1` when more than one instance of `DropDownViewModel` is created? How to solve this issue?

Comment: Side note: Are you sure your question is related to ASP.Net? If not - remove the tag. At the same time consider removing thank you text from the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that the issue is not WPF of MVVM related but is related with this code:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(_item);  //line1
```

The issue is that Messenger.Default looks to me like a static class and this static default messenger does not change. Is it correct? I cannot debug on your machine, but this looks to me as a code smell.

As a side note, you should be able switch and change the view models with no issue. To solve your design issue is to add your messenger instance inside the view model so you don't have a shared global state.

"Why is the app freezing on line1 when more than one instance of DropDownViewModel is created?"

Very likely that is not related with WPF code but again with the Messenger.Default.Send method code.

For your binging code, you can write without: "Path" just:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding Item}"  Height="30"/>
```

and it should work in all cases I am aware of.

Comment: I don't think {Binding PropertyName} and {Binding Path=PropertyName} has any difference.

Comment: @user1603970: Just wondering, how did this solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is MVVMLight you are using. The defining factor for the Messenger to know which recipients to send the message to, is `TMessage`, the type of the message:

```
public virtual void Register<TMessage>(object recipient, Action<TMessage> action)
```

So with your line

```
Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, this.GetItem1);
```

the ViewModel will now receive any message of type string. Both methods (`GetItem1` and `GetItem2`) are executed when you send a string type message.

The normal case is that you have a complex type for each Message, so you could use something like this, with DropDownId mirroring a unique identifier you attach to each DropDownViewModel.

```
public class DropDownSelectedItemMessage
{
    public string DropDownId { get; set; }
    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd register like this

```
Messenger.Default.Register<DropDownSelectedItemMessage>(this, this.GetItem1);
```

sending the message

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new DropDownSelectedItemMessage() { DropDownId = _id, SelectedItem = _item });
```

and in the message handler, you compare Ids:

```
private void string GetItem1(DropDownSelectedItemMessage message)
{
    if (message.DropDownId == _ddVM1.Id)
    {
        //perform some function
    }
}
```

However, my two cents: Forget about DropDownViewModel (keep both SelectedItem and ItemsSource properties on your actual ViewModel), completely refrain from using the Mediator pattern. Introduce a base class that implements and handles INotifyPropertyChanged so you can write properties on one line again. [Here](http://pastebin.com/tzWaQRhe)'s what I use.